# Blackberry can't accept connection via Mobile Network?

Tags: blackberry

On Blackberry, I want to open a server socket to listen connection come from others device.

Here's my code:


`String url = "socket://:12345;deviceside=true"; 

ServerSocketConnection scn = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open(url);

SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) scn.acceptAndOpen();`

Mobile network on that BB is ok, but it can not accept any connection.
I also use its mobile network to connect to other servers, it work fine when it is client socket.

I have tried with Wifi network, and it work fine.


`String url = "socket://:12345;interface=wifi"; 

ServerSocketConnection scn = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open(url);

SocketConnection sc = (SocketConnection) scn.acceptAndOpen();`

I think, Mobile Network Service prevented when others device connect to it, is it true?

Please explain to me, many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

On most cellular networks, there is no way to receive inbound connections on a device. Not only is the device behind a carrier level NAT, there are explicit blocks in place to prevent data from traversing the network when not initiated by a device.

In short, you can't run a server on a cell network.